# minifier node module write minified files to directory

Tags: node.js, npm, minify

I'm using minifier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/minifier) to minify my JS and CSS files like:

```
var input = __dirname + '/public/widgets/';
minifier.on('error', function(e){console.log('minify error', e);});
minifier.minify(input, {template: '{{filename}}.min.{{ext}}', clean: true});
```

How do I specify an output folder to write the minified files into?

Ideally if I had /public/widgets/account/account.js it would write to /public/mini-widgets/account/account.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ../ in the template option to get to the directory you want to:

```
var input = __dirname + '/public/widgets/';
minifier.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('minify error', new Date(), err);
});

minifier.minify(input, {template: '../../mini-widgets/{{filename}}.{{ext}}', clean: true});
```